# How to redirect to multiple URLs (php/javascript)

Tags: php, javascript

I have managed to redirect users based on their country code/IP using if/else statement.

```
<?php   
if ($geoplugin['geoplugin_countryCode'] == 'US') {    
    print '<script language="Javascript">window.location="http://domain.com/us";</script>';   
}       
else     
    print '<script language="Javascript">window.location="http://domain.com/ca";</script>';
}
?>
```

This works.  However, I have half dozen pages where visitors need to be redirected to based on their location.

How can I send users to various pages based on their locations?

I am very new to web development so please forgive me for asking a newb question.

Comment: next time try to format your code properly

Answer (score 0):

You could try a switch statement. [`switch` in PHP](http://php.net/switch) - [`switch` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) (hint: they're the same)

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `switch` case,
 NOTE:I am not using `break;` statement because using the `break` statement will increase the code.Use this

```
<?php

switch($geoplugin['geoplugin_countryCode']){
case'us':
case 'uk':

echo '<script language="Javascript">window.location="http://domain.com/"'.$geoplugin['geoplugin_countryCode'].';</script>';
}
?>
```